# java receiving connection at port

Tags: android

i am using a single port to receive both files and messages in a messenger app. i wanted to ask how can i differenntiate between the files and the messages? i have researched and found that m going to have to make a protoco, i tried but i cant seem to make one. is there any way to accomplish this?

right now i am receiving the connection like this :

```
public class ReceiveConnection extends Thread {

        Socket clientSocket = null;

        public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) 
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;

            SocketOperator.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             try {

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));



                        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {                



                             if (inputLine.contains("TEXT") == true)
                            {

                                Log.i("SocketOP","text");
                                appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);  
                        }


                        }
                         if (inputLine.contains("TEXT") == false)
                        {
                     InputStream is=clientSocket.getInputStream();

                 while(is!= null){
                            Log.i("SocketOP","filee");

appManager.fileReceived(is);
                     }


                        }
```

i have concatinated the string "TEXT" with my text message so it is coming through. putting an ELSE statement isnt working. how can i add a notifier with the file so that i know when the file is being received?

Comment: Please make an effort at formatting your code. It's really hard to follow in that form.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a message header that contains the following data:

1. Starts with unique byte sequence (2-4 bytes long) that acts as a message separator. This should be a unique non-text sequence that is not very common ( e.g. not CRLF or other control sequence).
2. Contains message type byte, so that you know if this is text message or file.
3. Contains length of the message, which helps while extracting the message.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i did not however understand your second point. and im also not sure about how to extract it back. im a beginner i am sorry :( could you elaborate a little. maybe an example? thank you so much.

Comment: or if you could give me a link explaining it a bit :) thank you.

Comment: On the receiving end you need to know type of data. You have text and file. You need to distinguish them because you treat them differently.

Comment: thats exactly what i am asking. how do i do that? i have racked my brains but in vain.

Comment: Before you send the data you send the header as described above. It helps you decode the data on receiving end.